# Always getting blank when extracting XML data in Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, xmltable

I have an XML data on an Oracle NCLOB:

```xml
<Storage xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Storage.xsd">
  <TableInfo>
    <Name>Table Name</Name>
    <Description>Table Description</Description>
    ...
  </TableInfo>
  <ColumnInfo>
    <Name>Column Name 1</Name>
    <Caption>Column Caption 1</Caption>
    ...
  </ColumnInfo>
  <ColumnInfo>
    <Name>Column Name 2</Name>
    <Caption>Column Caption 2</Caption>
    ...
  </ColumnInfo>
  ...
```

In Oracle this is my attempt at extracting the data:

```sql
...
CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE('/Storage/ColumnInfo'
  PASSING XMLTYPE(cv.dictionary_data) -- NCLOB column holding the XML
    COLUMNS
      tag VARCHAR2(500) PATH 'Name',
      caption VARCHAR2(500) PATH 'Caption'
) x
...
```

I've been trying both absolute and relative XPaths to replace `/Storage/ColumnInfo` but I keep getting blanks.

My goal is to have:

| ID | Tag | Caption |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Column Name 1 | Column Caption 1 |
| 1 | Column Name 2 | Column Caption 2 |
| 2 | Another Name 1 | Another Caption 1 |
| 2 | Another Name 2 | Another Caption 2 |
| 2 | Another Name 3 | Another Caption 3 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the namespace:

```
CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE(XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://tempuri.org/Storage.xsd'), '/Storage/ColumnInfo'
```

Comment: This seems to be what I needed. Thanks